# Querying in GraphQL, get the list of items associated to a category

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-amplify

I have a GraphQL Schema that has a project, and every project has associated interfaces. I was able to query it by @key by project number. But now, I am not able to get the items associated by a project. Here is some info:

My GraphQL Schema:

```
type Project 
  @model @key(fields: ["project_number"]) 
  {
    project_number: String!
    name: String!
    architect: String!
    interfaces: [Interface] @connection(name: "ProjectInterfaces")

  }
type Interface
  @model 
  {
    id: ID!             
    interface_name: String!
    version: String!
    release: String!    
    project: Project @connection(name: "ProjectInterfaces")          
  }
```

Here is the query I made:

```
query GetProject {
  getProject(project_number:"P100") {
    project_number
    name
    architect
    interfaces{
      items{
        id
        interface_name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Before I used the above schema without the key as project_number so I had something like `id:ID!` for project. With this, I was able to use the same query, and get the associated items with that ID. But now that I use the key for project_number it won't allow me to return the associated items. Perhaps it is a schema problem? I was thinking that it might be a resolver problem but I played around with the resolvers, and nothing seems to work. For background on the resolver. I believe it is due to the interfaceTable resolver. Here is the code that it autogenerated. I don't know what exactly to fix.

```
#set( $limit = $util.defaultIfNull($context.args.limit, 10) )
#set( $query = {
  "expression": "#connectionAttribute = :connectionAttribute",
  "expressionNames": {
      "#connectionAttribute": "interfaceProjectId"
  },
  "expressionValues": {
      ":connectionAttribute": {
          "S": "$context.source.id"
    }
  }
} )
{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "Query",
  "query":   $util.toJson($query),
  "scanIndexForward":   #if( $context.args.sortDirection )
    #if( $context.args.sortDirection == "ASC" )
true
    #else
false
    #end
  #else
true
  #end,
  "filter":   #if( $context.args.filter )
$util.transform.toDynamoDBFilterExpression($ctx.args.filter)
  #else
null
  #end,
  "limit": $limit,
  "nextToken":   #if( $context.args.nextToken )
"$context.args.nextToken"
  #else
null
  #end,
  "index": "gsi-ProjectInterfaces"
}
```

I also currently have a gsi index for the interfaces table called, "gsi-ProjectInterfaces"

Please let me know what you all think could be the issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your problem could be to remove the `@key` directive again.

Then query using `listProjects` and filter by `project_name`.

```
query listProjects {
  listProjects(filter: {
    project_number:{
      eq: "some-number"
    }
  }) {
    project_number
    name
    architect
    interfaces{
      items{
        id
        interface_name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is essentially a get query for just one item. Though it is a little more inefficient, which might not be a concern depending on how large you project is. (Make it work, make it right, make it fast -> fast last )